# Boto3 invocations of long-running Lambda runs break with TooManyRequestsException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

## Experience with "long-running" Lambda's

In my company, we recently ran into this behaviour, when triggering Lambdas, that run for > 60 seconds (boto3's default timeout for connection establishment and reads).

The beauty of the Lambda invocation with boto3 (using the 'InvocationType' 'RequestResponse') is, that the API returns the result state of the respective Lambda run, so we wanted to stick to that.

The issue seems to be, that the client fires to many requests per minute on the standing connection to the API. Therefore, we experimented with the [boto3 client configuration](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html), but increasing the read timeout resulted in new (unwanted) invocations after each timeout period and increasing the connection timeout triggered a new invocation, after the Lambda was finished.

Comment: Is it possible that the solution is to use the [Standard retry mode](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html#standard-retry-mode) instead of the default Legacy?

Comment: Hey @NickK9 , the topic has been a while for me, but reading the provided link I wouldn't see, how. Would you care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Workaround

As various investigations and experimentation with boto3's Lambda client did not result in a working setup using 'RequestResponse' invocations,
we circumvented the problem now by making use of Cloudwatch logs. For this, the Lambda has to be setup up to write to an accessible log group. Then, these logs can the queried for the state. Then you would invoke the Lambda and monitor it like this:

```
import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
logs_clients = boto3.client('logs')

invocation = lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName='your_lambda', 
    InvocationType='Event'
)

# Identifier of the invoked Lambda run
request_id = invocation['ResponseMetadata']['RequestID']

while True:
    # filter the logs for the Lambda end event
    events = logs_client.filter_log_events(
        logGroupName='your_lambda_loggroup',
        filterPattern=f'"END RequestId: {request_id}"'
    ).get('events', [])
    
    if len(events) > 0:
        # the Lambda invocation finished
        break
```

This approach works for us now, but it's honestly ugly. To make this approach slightly better, I recommend to set the time range filtering in the filter_log_events call.

One thing, that was not tested (yet): The above approach only tells, whether the Lambda terminated, but not the state (failed or successful) and the default logs don't hold anything useful in that regards. Therefore, I will investigate, if a Lambda run can know its own request id during runtime. Then the Lambda code can be prepared to also write error messages with the request id, which then can be filtered for again.

Comment: Or you could [increase the Boto3 timeout](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html).

Comment: I actually tried that, but that resulted in unwanted additional invocations (see original question, last section).

Comment: So you need to figure out why your client is making so many requests. Or use queues to sequence requests. Your approach of looking at the logs to see what's running is brittle, and is an X-Y solution.

Comment: I tried to do some digging there, but I was not successful in finding the reason for requests. The boto3 documentation was not telling (at least nothing, that I found), and I couldn't find the respective code parts while digging through the package's code. I agree, that my "solution" is far from good. I'm not happy about it myself (therefore it's name "workaround"), but given what I found in code, documentation and internet so far, it's at least something, that works as intended.
One part I don't understand in your response, is about the request queues: How would you do that?

Comment: Instead of a synchronous invoke, you put a message on an SQS queue and let it invoke Lambda asynchronously. If your caller needs to wait for the request to complete, you have the Lambda put a message on a different queue when it's done. One benefit of this if you're getting unexpected invocations is that you can put additional information into the invocation message, such as process and thread IDs (use attributes, leaving the message body for your actual request).

Comment: I see the slightly better elegance in your approach, but to me it still feels like a workaround: The invoking process would still loop in a monitoring setup. Let's not discuss here the pros/cons of our two different approaches. My point just is, that the AWS developed tooling seems to not provide the expected tooling. Is it worth it to create a ticket on their side then maybe?

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but expecting AWS to change to suit your needs is the wrong approach (and not likely to be successful). As I said in an early comment, if you're getting unexpected invocations then _you need to figure out why._ That's a bug in your code, and you're the only person that can solve it.